# Node/Mongoose - Create model and pass in logged in user details without email/password

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, postman

Fairly new to mongoose was hoping somebody could clear something up for me. I'm trying to create a poll app where a user can create polls.

I've implemented login so the user is saved in the headers under 'req.user', and in my poll I want to save the user who created the poll but I only want to save the id and name. I don't want the password and email etc.

Poll Schema

```
const pollSchema = new Schema({
    question: String,
    options: [optionsSchema],
    user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    voted: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]
});
```

Get logged in User from headers

```
const userId = await req.user;
const user = await User.findById(userId);
```

console.log(user) equals

```
{
  polls: [],
  _id: xxxxxxxx,
  name: 'Joe Bloggs',
  email: 'joeblogg@gmail.com',
  password: 'xxxxxxxx',
  __v: 0
}
```

I don't want to pass the password or email, I just want to pass the ID and name to the poll model like this:

```
const poll = await Poll.create({
        question,
        user: {
            _id: user.id,
            name: user.name
        },
        options: options.map(option => ({
            option,
            votes: 0
        })),
    });
```

Two problems:

The first is passing 'id' instead of '_id' causes this error:

```
'Poll validation failed: user: Cast to ObjectId failed for value'
```

Which confuses me, I thought mongoose would recognise 'id' as the same as '_id'.

If I change to '_id' it works again, but the Postman output is.

```
user: xxxxxxxxxxxxx (id)
```

So it returns the id, but it doesn't return the name from where I added:

```
name: user.name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating the Poll object you should only add user's Object id (not id and name) along with other poll data.

```
const poll = await Poll.create({
        question,
        user: ObjectId(user._id),
        options: options.map(option => ({
            option,
            votes: 0
     })),
});
```

When retrieving Poll data you can use,

```
const poll = await Poll.find().populate('user', '_id', 'name');
```

Ref: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#field-selection